# How to save time as UTC time in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I use

```
date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['time_zone']);
```

to set a users timezone on a page, I am wanting to know, how do I save current time to mysql in php with the current UTC date and time?  Also should I be storing it as a timestamp?

My existing site used datetime fields and when I saved a new item to mysql I could just use **now()** in the php part making the insert or update query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gmdate('U');` outputs the GMT/UTC timestamp of the specified timestamp based on the current timezone.

[See more information on the PHP Manual page](http://php.net/gmdate)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the relevant MySQL functions if you'd rather do it in your SQL:

```
SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_DATE(), UTC_TIME();
```

`UTC_TIMESTAMP()` is what you're looking for if you want to store as a `DATETIME` field